# Assigning a variable to a textBox once it has been declared

Tags: vb.net

I am a fairly new user to VB, and was wondering why the following code didn't give me the answer that I was looking for:

```
Dim name, orderNumber, cityStateZip, address As String
name = nameTextBox.text
orderNumber = orderNumberTextBox.Text
cityStateZip = cityStateZipTextBox.Text
address = addressTextBox.Text

if (name = "" OrElse orderNumber = "" OrElse cityStateZip = "" OrElse address = "") Then
    MessageBox.Show("Please enter a Salesperson's name", "Input Error",
                        MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error)
End If
```

The above code would not present the MessageBox. However, if I 'Dim' all of the variables (Name, OrderNumber, etc.), it will work.

I was wondering why that is the case?

Comment: Copied and pasted your code into a Button_Click event. With empty textboxes, it compiles and shows a MessageBox. Therefore, there seems to be something else going wrong in your code.

Comment: Can you compile the code? if Not turn off the Option strict your project properties.

Comment: If as you say so, that its working having each of them declared, then why not do that if it solves your problem? Or try `name Is Nothing` and use `Or` instead of `OrElse`

Comment: Hey guys, thanks for the answers! @AdorableVB I was just inquiring as to why it did not work for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Dim name, orderNumber, cityStateZip, address As String
name = nameTextBox.text
orderNumber = orderNumberTextBox.Text
cityStateZip = cityStateZipTextBox.Text
address = addressTextBox.Text
```

is not the same as

```
Dim name = nameTextBox.text
Dim orderNumber = orderNumberTextBox.Text
Dim cityStateZip = cityStateZipTextBox.Text
Dim address = addressTextBox.Text
```

The latter uses implicit typing, or the compiler gets the type from the context. The type is implied, according to the type of the variable which is being assigned to it. i.e. `nameTextBox.text` property is a String, and the compiler figures this out, and you have the `name` variable implicitly typed as a String. You can explicitly type them, as in your original code. However, for readability, you could use this method:

```
Dim name As String = nameTextBox.text
Dim orderNumber As String = orderNumberTextBox.Text
Dim cityStateZip As String = cityStateZipTextBox.Text
Dim address As String = addressTextBox.Text
```

This all being said, I can't think of any reason why you need to Dim them individually (if I understood correctly), and all these methods should effectively work the same in your code.

Answer (score 0):

Try like this

```
Dim name As String
Dim orderNumber As String
Dim cityStateZip As String
Dim address As String

orderNumber = Me.orderNumberTextBox.Text
cityStateZip = Me.cityStateZipTextBox.Text
address = Me.addressTextBox.Text //  "Me" refers to the current form
```

---

Comment: Hey, thanks for answering however I know how to make it work, I was wondering why the above method (from op) didn't work.